# blocking facebook on my computer without deleting the account

Tags: facebook

This may sound odd but, I would like to block facebook on my computer.  I don't want to give it up altogether but make it harder for me by accessing it by my phone.  I spend way too much time on facebook and want to cut it down.  I've tried the apps to block websites like fb from my computer, and it worked fine until I found you could just unclick that app in tools and there it was.  I could still connect to it on my phone but since I hate the way it looks I don't stay on it for very long.  Yeah, I know I am nuts and have 0 self control.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an application to block sites when accessing it.

(a) Web Monitoring Program

(b) OpenDNS to Protect Your Entire Network

You could also edit the hostfile [hosts] that can be seen in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Go to the bottom of the document and enter 127.0.0.1  and press Enter. Replace  with the website that you want to block (facebook.com). 
Enter another line with the same information except add the “www.” before the website. In essence you should have two entries per website that you want to block: 127.0.0.1 facebook.com AND 127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com.

Repeat this for each website that you want to block.
Save the file. Do not change the name, file type, or location of the file. Simply save the changes you’ve made. You may have to restart your browser for the changes to take effect.